# c++ exception not caught for simdjson library

Tags: c++, json, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to use the simdjson library: https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson#documentation

However the json I need to parse comes over a websocket connection and does not always contain the same keys. Therefore sometimes trying to extract a value by key from the parsed json object throws an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'simdjson::simdjson_error'
  what():  The JSON field referenced does not exist in this object.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Example code below of trying to get the exception handling to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

#include "simdjson.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace simdjson;

int main() {

    auto cars_json = R"( [
  { "make": "Toyota", "model": "Camry",  "year": 2018, "tire_pressure": [ 40.1, 39.9, 37.7, 40.4 ] },
  { "make": "Kia",    "model": "Soul",   "year": 2012, "tire_pressure": [ 30.1, 31.0, 28.6, 28.7 ] },
  { "make": "Toyota", "model": "Tercel", "year": 1999, "tire_pressure": [ 29.8, 30.0, 30.2, 30.5 ] }
] )"_padded;

    simdjson::error_code error_c;

    dom::parser  parser;
    dom::object  doc;
    dom::element elem;

    const char* value;

    doc = parser.parse(cars_json);

    try
    {
        doc["clOrdID"].get<const char*>().tie(value, error_c);
    } 
    catch (simdjson_error e)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've read the documentation on error handling for the library here:
https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/blob/master/doc/basics.md#error-handling

However, using a try-catch block and the error handling method described in the documentation above both still cause the program to exit. I'm very new to c++ programming and therefore also exception handling in the language - any guidance on how to catch any exception from this library would be appreciated!

Comment: Note: Usually you want to catch exceptions not by value, but by const reference, as in `catch (const simdjson_error& e)`.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code step by step to check the actually fired exception? Worst case you can do `catch(...)` but this not a good practice if you want to implement specific recovery to specific errors.

Comment: i tried catch(...) as well and it still failed. not sure how to find out the actually fired exception as you say.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should move the `parser.parse(cars_json);` into the `try / catch` block, in order to catch parser exception

```
try {
    doc = parser.parse(cars_json);
} catch (simdjson::simdjson_error e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

then you might realize that the `parser` doesn't return `simdjson::dom::object` but `simdjson::dom::array` instead.

Here's updated example with conversion to `const char*`

```
const char* value;

try {
    auto root = parser.parse(cars_json);
    cout << "root: " << root.type() << endl;

    auto car = root.at(0);
    if(car["make"].is_string()){
        cout << "first car: " << car["make"] << endl;
    }

    //check non-existing element
    if(car["foo"].is_string()){
        // exception won't be thrown
    }

    std::string_view sv = root.at(1)["model"];
    cout << "string view: " << sv << endl;
    //conversion to const char*
    value = std::string(sv).c_str();
    cout << "const char: " << value << endl;


} catch (const simdjson::simdjson_error &e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

the output should be:

```
root: array
first car: "Toyota"
string view: Soul
const char: Soul
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I was having the same issue using release `v0.9.6` ([from the documentation's recommended CMake Installation](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson/blob/master/doc/basics.md#using-simdjson-as-a-cmake-dependency))

The only other answer never really makes the code work.

I upgraded to `v3.1.6`, the latest as of the writing of this answer, then deleted my CMake folders, and this bug was fixed.